# Python sklearn. Why I received warnings first time only?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lasso-regression

I received warnings first time only.
Is this normal?

```
>>> cv=LassoCV(cv=10).fit(x,y)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scikit_learn-0.14.1-py2.7-win32.egg\sklearn\linear_model\coordinate_descent.py:418: UserWarning: Objective did not converge. You might want to increase the number of iterations
  ' to increase the number of iterations')
>>> cv=LassoCV(cv=10).fit(x,y) 
>>>
```

Comment: I think yeah.. That's normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because the "objective did not converge". The maximum iterations are by default 1000 and you are not setting them. Try setting the `max_iter` parameter to a higher value to avoid the warning.

Comment: Ok thanks but I was only wondering why i receive the warnings only one time.

Comment: maybe it converged for other iterations but not one!

Answer (score 5):

It's because the python warnings filter is set to just warn the first time it catches a particular warning by default.

If you  want to get all the warnings, just add this:

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("always")
```